# Parse numbers from a string and push them to an array

Tags: javascript, string

So I have a strings like this: `'5-2 7-1 8-9 7-4 1-3 1-0 2-8 8-0 6-9'`, it's always in this form (number, dash, number, space, number, dash, ..)

What I want to do is to transform this in to an array of integers: [5, 2, 7, 1, 8, ..., 9]
I had this solution

```
var str = '5-2 7-1 8-9 7-4 1-3 1-0 2-8 8-0 6-9';
numbers = str.replace('-', ' ').split(' ').map(function(entry) { return parseInt(entry); }); 
// ==> [ 5, 2, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 2, 8, 6 ] WTF!!
```

So I went with this

```
var str = '5-2 7-1 8-9 7-4 1-3 1-0 2-8 8-0 6-9';
numbers = str.split(' ').join('').split('-').join('').split('').map(function(num) {
 return parseInt(num); 
}); // ==> [ 5, 2, 7, 1, 8, 9, 7, 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 8, 8, 0, 6, 9 ] All good!
```

But I don't know why the first solution doesn't work, I know the problem is with the `str.replace` but I can't figure out why it produce this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` method only replaces the first occurrence by default. You need to use a regular expression to replace all of them:

```
var str = '5-2 7-1 8-9 7-4 1-3 1-0 2-8 8-0 6-9';
numbers = str.replace(/-/g, ' ').split(' ').map(function(entry) { 
//                       ^ The g flag makes the regex match all occurrences
    return parseInt(entry);
});
```

Comment: gah, you beat me to it

Comment: How about `str.split(/[\s-]/).map(Number)`?

Comment: @elclanrs - Yep, that would work but doesn't answer the question as to why the OPs attempt doesn't.

Comment: @elclanrs that's even better!

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` only replaces the first occurrence. Use a regex and do a global replace
`numbers = str.replace(/-/g, ' ')....`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uYKV6/10/

```
var str, strArr, regex;

str = '5-2 7-1 8-9 7-4 1-3 1-0 2-8 8-0 6-9';
regex = new RegExp("-", 'g');
str = str.replace(regex, " ");
strArr = str.split(" ");
console.log(strArr);
```